# Sequence of execution for variable creation and static block

Tags: java

```
class F
{
    static
    {
      i = 1;
    }
    static int i = 2;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The output of this execution is `2`. Can someone explain why not `1`? In which sequence variables are getting created and initialized and static block is executed?

Comment: Hi, you need to ask a question!

Comment: Thanks Adam. Output of this execution is '2', Can someone explain why not '1'. In which sequence variables are getting created and initialized and static block is executed.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

kindly check java documentation.

then clearly mentioned no matter how may static blocks are there they will be executed as a single block in the order they appear

So,

My understanding here is java is looking your code as

```
static{
i=1;
i=2;
}
```

static int i;

that is why you are getting output 2

hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks Avi. If i add System.out.println(i); in static block below i = 1; I get compile time error.